# TFS Work Item copy and append feature

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am trying to copy the content of one text field(say A) in TFS work item to another text field(say B) in the same work item, without deleting the exsting content of field B. I have tried all the controls but nothing has seemed useful. can someone help me here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this on just one work item or in bulk?

If on just one work item what's stopping your from just copy/pasting as usual?

If in bulk I'd suggest using the TFS API and a little code to accomplish this.